# DaisyUI dropdown button inside collapse is hidden inside container

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, daisyui

Hello i have a small issue with daisyUI first time trying it. Here's my template code and example picture. Basically the issue i'm facing is that the dropdown menu inside the collapse element is not shown because it's hidden by the content of the collapse. How can i fix this? I tried using z-index to 99 but that didnt seem to work. And adding ! to the dropdown makes it expand the content of the collapse but i need go over the end of the collapse element.

```
  <div
    tabindex="0"
    class="collapse collapse-open border border-base-300 bg-red-200"
  >
    <div class="collapse-title text-xl font-medium">
      I have collapse-open class
    </div>
    <div class="collapse-content">
      <details class="dropdown">
        <summary class="m-1 btn">open or close</summary>
        <ul
          class="p-2 shadow menu dropdown-content z-[99] bg-base-100 rounded-box w-52"
        >
          <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </details>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXqj2.png)

I tried adding the important tag on the dropdown-content and dropdown menu class but that just expands the container which is not what i want to achieve. I also tried to tinker with the overflow attribute but that didnt seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to override the `overflow: hidden` declaration from the `.collapse` rule from Daisy UI to `overflow: visible`.

For example, with `overflow: visible !important` via the `!overflow-visible` class:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daisyui@4.4.23/dist/full.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.0"></script>

<div tabindex="0" class="collapse collapse-open border border-base-300 bg-red-200 !overflow-visible">
  <div class="collapse-title text-xl font-medium">
    I have collapse-open class
  </div>
  <div class="collapse-content">
    <details class="dropdown">
      <summary class="m-1 btn">open or close</summary>
      <ul class="p-2 shadow menu dropdown-content z-[99] bg-base-100 rounded-box w-52">
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Item 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </details>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually solved it. Thank you a lot however i went a bit further ahead with my code and now facing a new issue. Basically i am having nested collapse elements. I tried the same with the way using overflow visible on the main collapse however this causes the collapse not to work properly to contain the elements and always display the elements